# C++ using 'this' as a parameter

Tags: c++

I have a class which looks approximately like this:

```
class MeshClass
{
public:
    Anchor getAnchorPoint(x, y)
    {
      return Anchor( this, x, y );
    }
private:
    points[x*y];
}
```

I want to make another class which represents an "Anchor" point which can get access to the Mesh and modify the point, like this:

```
class Anchor
{
public:
    Anchor(&MeshClass, x, y)
    moveAnchor(x, y);
}
```

The problem is when I try to make the `Anchor` in the `MeshClass::getAnchorPoint` method, something like `return Anchor(this, x, y)` but because `this` is const I can't.  As a workaround until I get this figured out I have Anchor accepting a reference to the point and moveAnchor moves the point directly.

**Edit:** The problem was most likely something dumb I was doing with trying to use a Reference.  I changed to using a pointer like I normally would and I can pass in `this` with no complaints from the compiler.  I'm almost certain I was getting an error related to this being const, but I can't recreate it so I must just be out of my mind.

Comment: Hi, for me your isn't suppose to compile ... it does ?

Comment: It probably doesn't (yet) :)  Bear in mind that (at least in plain old C), if the type isn't specified, it defaults to int, but throws a warning.

Comment: Please post the actual code you want to use and the error it generates. (Not how you tried to work around that error.) It's currently a little to hard to guess what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ye beacause at first, you are suppose to have something like that :  return Anchor(*this, x, y); if Anchor receives a ref.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C++, this is a pointer, not a reference.  You could do something like this:

```
class Anchor; //forward declaration

class MeshClass
{
public:
    Anchor getAnchorPoint(int x, int y)
    {
        return Anchor(*this, x, y );
    }
private:
    int points[WIDTH*HEIGHT];
}

class Anchor
{
public:
    Anchor(MeshClass &mc, int x, int y);
}
```

Comment: This was probably my problem.  I decided to have Anchor accept a pointer rather than a reference, in which case `this` now seems to work fine as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The constness of *this* is not a problem. The pointer itself is const, not the value it points to.

Your real problem is here:

```
class MeshClass
{
public:
    Anchor getAnchorPoint(x, y)
    { 
       return Anchor( *this, x, y );
    }
 private:
     points[x*y];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think `this` is const?  `this` is a pointer, not a reference.  Shouldn't it be `return Anchor( *this, x, y);`?

Comment: Technically, this actually _is_ const, *this is not.

Comment: Technically, `this` is not const-qualified. It's not modifiable because it's an rvalue, not because it's const. This means that `this` has type `Class *`, but *not* `Class *const`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you change Anchor to accept a `const MeshClass&` as parameter, or cast *this* as `(MeshClass)` when creating the Anchor ?
I am not sure if one can use `const_cast<MeshClass>(this)` to remove the constness of `this`.